# I can facebook live streaming, but that type Onle me

Tags: facebook

My `GraphRequest` code

```
GraphRequest livestream = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(
    graphRequest.getAccessToken(),
    "/" + graphRequest.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "/live_videos",
    new JSONObject("{\"title\":\"todayLive\",\"description\":\"This is the live video for today.\", \"status\" : \"LIVE_NOW\", \"targeting\" : \"\"}"),
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            Log.e("live : ", response.toString());

            jsonString = response.getJSONObject().toString();
        }
    });
livestream.executeAsync();
```

This works, but I only get `private` streams. 
How do I get only `public` streams?

Comment: Check what privacy level you have set for content published through the app under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications (“App Visibility” is what its called in the English language version.)

Comment: Codeformatting, spelling errors and rephrasing.